# Markov inequality question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $x$ be a random variable and let $m = \sqrt[3]{\Bbb E[X^3]}.$
Show that, for each $a \gt 0$, then $\Bbb P[X \geq a\cdot m] \leq \frac{1}{a^3}.$

If anyone could help I'll appreciate.

Comment: Notice $\mathbf{E}(X) = \mathbf{E}(X; X \leq a m) + \mathbf{E}(X; X > am),$ where the $;$ stands for "integrating on the set" (that is to say, multiplication by an indicator function). Realise that $X > c$ and $X^3 > c^3$ are equivalent relations.

Comment: Do we need $X$ to be a nonnegative random variable?

Comment: Yes X should be a nonnegative random variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Markov you have 
$$P[X\geq a]\leq \frac{E[X]}{a}$$
and so 
$$P[X\geq a\cdot m]\leq P[X^3\geq a^3m^3]\leq \frac{E[X^3]}{a^3\cdot (E[X^3])}=\frac{1}{a^3}.$$